# require() fails when ran from html but works when running javascript directly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Basically, whenever I attempt to run the code from the javascript it is able to find `http.js` in what I assume is node. However, when running on a webpage from an HTML is reports the error:

> GET `http://localhost:63342/weather/https.js`

What I think is wrong is that the runtime location is different between the two and they are just pulling from two different locations. This is done in web storm.

The code is nothing more than a `<script src=...>` in the HTML and `require("https")` in the javascript. When running through HTML I change the require part to

```
require(['https'], function (https) {
    https=require("https")
});
```

for async reasons I believe.

Comment: https is a core module of node js. thats why its available on server side but there is no such thing for browser.

Comment: You need to use a module bundler such as webpack or browserify as node.js JavaScript doesn't work in the browser directly.

Comment: Thanks, Inus/Jake. You guys are correct.  I installed browserify and now it works!